# Return relative position of Nth non-zero value in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, named-function

I have been trying to come up with a way to return the relative position of the nth non-zero value in a row range within Google Sheets. I have asked this question on Reddit too (https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/130v500/how_to_find_the_position_of_nth_nonzero_value_in/), and a helpful person provided a script to create a corresponding function to do this; however, I cannot get this to work when copying it over to Apps Script.

What I was provided was:

> Returns "nth" non-zero value position, in "range"(single row or column)
>
> NTH_NZPOS(range,nth)
> =let(s,tocol(range),
> iferror(
> index(
> reduce(,sequence(rows(s)),
> lambda(a,i,if(ne(index(s,i,1),0),if(isblank(a),{i},{a;i}),a))),
> nth,1),
> "")
> )
> NTH_NZPOS({0,0,5,0,0,8,0},1) => 3
> NTH_NZPOS({0,0,5,0,0,8,0},2) => 6
> NTH_NZPOS({0,0,5,0,0,8,0},3) => ""

Which I have tried to put into Apps Script as below, which results in several errors.

```
function NTH_NZPOS(range,nth)
 {
  return =let(s,tocol(range),
  iferror(
    index(
      reduce(,sequence(rows(s)),
        lambda(a,i,if(ne(index(s,i,1),0),if(isblank(a),{i},{a;i}),a))),
    nth,1),
  "")
);
}
```

I am completely lost for how to adjust this code to work. Any solution that returns the relative position of the Nth non-zero value would be great, it doesn't have to involve a custom function (ideally working within the pre-built functions that come with Sheets would be ideal)

Inputting the function above into Apps Script results in several errors. Deleting the highlighted errors of course doesn't result in a working function.

Comment: It's not apps script. It's [tag:named-function]

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input **and** expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use this function:

1. Click on `Data` then `Named Functions` in the top menu.
2. **Name** your function `NTH_NZPOS`, provide the **Argument placeholders** values of `range` & `nth`, then copy/paste the below formula into the **Formula definition** section.

```
=let(s,tocol(range), iferror( index( reduce(,sequence(rows(s)), lambda(a,i,if(ne(index(s,i,1),0),if(isblank(a),{i},{a;i}),a))), nth,1), "") )
```

***When you're done it should look like this:***

[image: Named Functions]

***Then to use it you just treat it like a regular function and enter `=NTH_NZPOS()` into a cell, provide the range, a number for which nth non-zero value you want the position of and you're good to go!***